# pass form vars through wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, variables

Im kind of new to php, and am trying to learn how to accomplish a normaly simple task, but am running into language barrier :). Hoping you guys have some advise or a few code snippets to guide me in the right direction.

I'm using a wordpress site, and have built a page within it (using new page post),  inside this page ive built a form that is calling an external js file, heres a link to this page:

```
    ( http://69.195.124.135/~fivestk2/cash-closing-cost-estimator/).
```

Where im having trouble is how to pass the form vars over to the next page. the next page should just be a summary of the vars,  and a few extra fields to input an email by the user so that the summarized page can be emailed.

my logic is that i should be able to do this below for each var in my form

```
    <form method="post" action="resultvars.php">

    <input type="text" var="var1"/><br/>
    <input type="text" var="var2"/><br/>
    <input type="text" var="var3"/><br/>
    <input type="text" var="var4"/><br/>

    <input type="submit" var="submit"/>

    </form>
```

accesing the posted page (resultvars.php) i thought would fill in the vars into the results page but all i get when i try is a page displaying code.

```
    <?php $name0 = $_POST['name0'];

    $var1 = $_POST['var1']; 
    $var2 = $_POST['var2']; 
    $var3 = $_POST['var3']; 
    $var4 = $_POST['var4'];

    echo $name0.'<br/><br/>'; 
    echo $name1.'<br/><br/>'; 
    echo $name2.'<br/><br/>'; 
    echo $name3.'<br/><br/>'; 
    echo $name3.'<br/><br/>';

    ?>
```

I just a little advise on how to code my original form above so that it will work inside these wordpress pages, i think this example i found is what i need, but im new to working with this stuff. Thanks for reading

Comment: I recommend creating a page in the wordpress back end. Then you have http://www.mysite.com/newpage for example. Create a wordpress template with the relevant code you wish to output etc and select the page to work with this template. Then on the form put the action to go to this newly created page.

Comment: usually this means that your server is not configured to process the php. Thus it simply sends the file "as is" to the client and your browser displays the code. See either the php site or the webservers documentation for instructions on how to make it process php code.

Comment: I would recommend you delete the Wordpress installation, learn some php. Then reconsider if Wordpress is want you need for whatever projecy you are making.

Comment: try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507872/how-to-pass-form-input-to-wordpress-page/42508237#42508237

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to create your page, but for now, sticking to your issue, you should change your HTML code to this -

```
<form method="POST" action="resultvars.php">

    <input type="text" name="var1" value="Var 4"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="var2" value="Var 4"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="var3" value="Var 4"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="var4" value="Var 4"/><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Couple that with some minor changes to your PHP and you should be able to view the Posted values -

```
<?php
$var1 = $_POST['var1']; 
$var2 = $_POST['var2']; 
$var3 = $_POST['var3']; 
$var4 = $_POST['var4'];

echo $var1.'<br/><br/>'; // You could just do - echo $_POST['var1'].'<br/><br/>';
echo $var2.'<br/><br/>'; 
echo $var3.'<br/><br/>'; 
echo $var4.'<br/><br/>';

?>
```