# How to pass form input to Wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I've got a small but persistent issue on my WordPress website.

On my homepage I have a form:

```
<form method='post' action='/test/' > 
    Input: <input type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

With this form I'm trying to pass and use the `input` value on another page.

I believe `action` should `=  'test.php'` not `/test/` (`/test/` is the URL of a regular WordPress page). I can't seem to access any `X.php` pages in the URL, as it 404's every time (excluding `index.php`, which doesn't 404, instead it just redirects from `domain.com/index.php` to `domain.com`

I've tried creating a new php template (which I can use as a page template to customize the `/test/` page), but it still 404's if I try to use `action = 'new-template.php'` in the form.

Any suggestions on how I can pass the form data to another page in this scenario?

Comment: look at this [task here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127054/how-to-pass-data-between-wordpress-pages) ist the same question.

Comment: I have already read that, however it was still 404ing for me.

Comment: to diagnose this problem we need to know what webserver you're using, what its configuration is, and the directory structure it's serving from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a simple example,

1st create a template and assign it to page eg. test123 // you can hide it from custom site map creation.

then you can call that page as form submit page

```
<form method='post' action='<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/test123/' >
```

try this you can write your php code inside the template.

Comment: I was stupidly trying to put the form (with PHP) directly into a WordPress page, which was causing the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: your welcome, actually wordpress is not the matter, think with php and basic concepts.